# eclipse: cant create run configuration for gwt project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I would like to launch a GWT application from Eclipse. However, when I click "Run As.." I don't get any options and I can't create a run configuration.

I followed this link:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0

However, in my GWT tab, I cannot change anything. And the "RUN" button is never active.

Why doesnt Eclipse recognize it as a GWT project automatically?

How can I get this to work?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

When I clicked on the "GOOGLE"-Option in the context menu and clicked on GWT COMPILE, it said that my project is not a GWT project.

I dont get that. I created it using the mojo gwt maven plugin and I can launch it via the command-line.

**EDIT 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>GWTProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.7.0</gwtVersion>

        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.6 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process-classes" 
            update them in DevMode -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>GWTProject.html</runTarget>
                    <modules>
                        <module>de.abc.GWTProject.GWTProject</module>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error is:

```
Missing required argument 'module[s]'
Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0
```

Which are the models, apart from the already specified

```
<modules>
    <module>de.abc.GWTProject.GWTProject</module>
</modules>
```

**EDIT**

Under the maven dependencies I have:

```
gwt-servlet-2.7.0.jar
gwt-user-2.7.0.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
gwt-dev-2.7.0.jar
a couple of jars beginning with asm-
junit
hamcrest
```

all from my local maven repository.

Wouldn't I have gotten some compiler errors otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project

--> properties --> Google --> Web Toolkit

Click on "Use Google Web Toolkit" check box

and select a GWT SDK

---

Right click on your project

--> properties --> Java Build Path

ensure you have GWT sdk

Comment: I did that, I also specified src/main/webapp as war directory. Now I get an error because of the modules. I posted my POM above, maybe you can have another look.

Comment: looks like your classpath is missing gwt jars, i have added additional steps,please verify it

Comment: okay, I downloaded gwt 2.7.0 and put the folder into my projet folder. Then I specified this folder as the web toolkit in the project properties. Several jar files are now in my build path (gwt-user, gwt-codeserver,...) however, I still get the same message. Why do I need to add those jars? I thought thats exactly what maven is supposed to take care of...

Comment: Yes. Maven should take care of it, expand maven dependencies in your java build path and ensure that you have gwt jars, if you have gwt jars there and then you dont need to add the jars in your lib.

Comment: I checked and edited my answer. gotta got now, will be back in a couple of hours.

Comment: Any ideas? I generated the project again, went to the properties, pointed it to the webapp directory and checked that it should use the GWT SDK (after that it added the necessary jars to my project again, which is weird because its not necessary) but I still get the modules error.